# Getting generic currency sign instead of $ in .NET application

Tags: vb.net, currency-formatting

In our VB .NET application, we use "c0" and "c2" format strings to display currency values all over the place.

Recently, users have had issues where these currency values don't show up correctly with a $ sign, but with some weird symbol, ¤. Through wikipedia, I found out it's the generic currency symbol: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_(typography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29)

I've seen the problem happen on my machine ONCE, and haven't been able to recreate it since. It went away when I restarted the application. In fact, as soon as I saw the problem, I started another instance of the application but $ signs showed up fine in that second instance.

I'd appreciate any insights on how to fix this weird issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally got hold of a build where this problem happened consistently.

Turned out, we use RedGate SQL Compare to compare and update users' databases, and it was a bug in RedGate that changed our Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture from "en-US" to "". That in turns changed the Globalization.CultureInfor.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol to the generic sign ¤.

I'm still unclear as to why the issue happened with some databases and not others, but we've certainly found our workaround.

The RedGate problem was identified in this forum thread: http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=10864 and has been fixed since their [March 2011 release](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=SQL%20Data%20Compare&c=SQL_Data_Compare%5Carticles%5Cversion_9xx_SQLDataCompare.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly set the format locale before using your format strings.